# How add two times in c?

Tags: c, time

I am trying to add two times like 20:30 + 1:40 = 22h 10m.
I'm having a problem with the remainder after the dot

```
#include <stdio.h>

float walking (float start,float duration);

int main() {
  printf ("finish = %.2f", walking(20.30, 1.40));
  return 0;
}

float walking(float start, float duration) {
  int finMinuites = (int)(start * 100) % 100 + (int)(duration * 100) % 100;
  int finHours = (start * 100) / 100 + (duration * 100) / 100;

  if (finMinuites >= 60) {
    finMinuites -= 60;
    finHours++;
  }

  if (finHours >= 24)
    finHours -= 24;

    return finHours + finMinuites / 100;
  }
```

Comment: Or (assuming you only want minute accuracy), you can just use an integer for minutes and then get the `m/60` and `m%60` when you want to display the times.

Comment: I'd avoid `float` for time values. Note that `12.30` (approx. 12 and 1/3 hours) is _not_ the same as `12:30` (exactly 12 and 1/2 hours). How about (e.g.) `const char *str = "12:30"; int sec; int h; int m; sscanf(str,"%d:%d",&h,&m); sec = (h * 3600) + (m * 60);` ?

Comment: *"I'm having a problem with the remainder after the dot"* is not a problem description

Comment: Your main problem is that in `return finHours + finMinuites/100` you're doing integer division.  You'd want `return finHours + finMinuites/100.` (note the extra dot).

Comment: But with that said, this approach is never going to work too well.  Type `float` can't represent decimal fractions perfectly, but here you depend on it to.  After fixing the aforementioned bug, I get an answer of `22.09`, whereas the correct answer would be 22:10.  The problem is unavoidable roundoff error, because numbers like 20.30 aren't exact.

Comment: @SteveSummit I had the same rounding error and I fixed it with `round()`

Comment: @CraigEstey If you look at the code more carefully, 12.30 is being *interpreted* as 12:30, by fiat.

Comment: I'm sorry for poor English, but I have to learn it while I'm also learning programming.

Comment: Using floating point for a time value is going to have lots of issues. You would be better off storing time in terms of absolute minutes or seconds.

Comment: I quickly scanned the comments, and did not see the suggestion of using strings for time duration, so I will introduce the idea as one to consider.  i.e. change prototype to `float walking (char *start, char *duration);`  Called eg as: `printf ("finish = %.2f",walking("20.30", "1.40"));` .  Then parse strings using your favorite string to number conversion, then convert hours and minutes to seconds for both start time, and duration.  Then use `%` and `/` operators as shown in one of the answers below to reconvert into a single value of resulting time back into hours and minutes:  Htotal.Mtotal

Comment: why `(start * 100) / 100` and `(duration * 100) / 100`? They do nothing except when overflowing

Comment: @ryyker Based on your comment, I've proposed an answer... Thanks for the notion.. It turns out to be quite elegant... `:-)`

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to store time in a float then here is a solution:

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

float walking(float start,float duration);
int main() {
    printf("finish = %.2f",walking(20.30, 1.40));
    return 0;
}
int toMinutes(float time){
    int t = (int)round((time*100));
    int hours = t/100;
    int min = t - hours * 100;
    return hours*60+min;
}
float toFloat(int minutes){
    int hours = minutes/60;
    int min = minutes - hours * 60;
    float t = hours * 100;
    t += min;
    t /= 100;
    return t;
}
float walking(float start,float duration){
    int mins = toMinutes(start) + toMinutes(duration);
    int day = 24*60;
    while(mins > day){
        mins -= day;
    }

    return toFloat(mins);
}
```

But I would suggest storing the minutes as an int instead.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @ryyker, you can make life simple with strings without changing the calling parameters:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double walking( double bgn, double dur ) {
    printf( "Start = %5.2f  duration = %5.2f  ", bgn, dur );
    char str[32];

    sprintf( str, "%.2f %.2f", bgn, dur );
    int res = 0, cnt = 1;
    for( char *cp = str; ( cp = strtok( cp, " ." ) ) != NULL; cp = NULL )
        res += atoi( cp ) * (cnt&1 ? 60 : 1), cnt++;

    return res/60%24 + ((res%60)*0.01);
}

int main() {
    double pairs[][2] = {
        { 20.30,  1.40 },
        {  1.47,  1.13 },
        {  0.00,  1.13 },
        {  0.00,  0.00 },
        { 23.59,  0.01 },
        { 12.00, 48.27 },
    };

    for( int i = 0; i < sizeof pairs/sizeof pairs[0]; i++ )
        printf ( "finish = %5.2f\n", walking( pairs[i][0], pairs[i][1] ) );

    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
Start = 20.30  duration =  1.40  finish = 22.10
Start =  1.47  duration =  1.13  finish =  3.00
Start =  0.00  duration =  1.13  finish =  1.13
Start =  0.00  duration =  0.00  finish =  0.00
Start = 23.59  duration =  0.01  finish =  0.00
Start = 12.00  duration = 48.27  finish = 12.27
```

EDIT:

It has been noted that this approach may not work for `Dr Who` and other time travellers. The following shows the necessary changes for those for whom the second law of thermodynamics does not apply:

```
sprintf( str, "%.2f %.2f", bgn, dur );
int res = 0, cnt = 1, sgn = 1;
for( char *cp = str; ( cp = strtok( cp, " ." ) ) != NULL; cp = NULL, cnt++ )
    res += atoi( cp )
        * (cnt&1 ? 60 : 1)
        * sgn,
    sgn = *cp == '-' ? -1 : 1;

/* then one additional test case */

    { 12.00, -2.30 },

/* Output of the single test case: */

Start = 12.00  duration = -2.30  finish =  9.30
```

Since the first parameter shown in the OP seems to use a 24hr clock, no attempt has been made to test starting at "minus eleven-thirty".

Enjoy your walk. Take the garbage out with you when you leave...

Comment: Corner concerns that OP may/may not care about.  This approach fails when `duration < 0` as `atoi(cp)` of minutes does not have the _sign_.  `sprintf()` risks buffer overflow with pathologically large `double` values.  BTW, nice test harness.

Comment: Note: `floor(res/60.0)` simpler as `res/60`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Re: "duration < 0" -- **Caveat:** "Does not necessarily work for time travellers." `:-)` Re: "buffer overrun" -- `bgn` is 24hr clock, and hard for duration of a walk (`dur`) to be more than a few hours. `:-)` Re: "floor( )" Thank you... Better answer... Fixing... Too focussed on "double"... `:-)`

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Always up for a challenge... Check out the edit version `:)`

Comment: Yes better. Although we are having fun with time travel, do consider a negative "duration" may result form a calculation involving a daylight savings time shift or even a more rare timezone change.  Yes, this is all beyond OP's learning exercise.  BTW, why `cp = NULL`?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica ONLY JUST got rid of one more line of code... 24hr modulo now in return calculation... Re: `cp = NULL` -- setup for next invocation of `strtok( )`... Most coders think two separate invocations are required... `:-)` Re: "negative duration"... Good point! You're right. Hadn't thought of that, but... Thank you `:-)`

Answer (score 1):

The difficult part is to break a floating point variable (FP) properly.

`float/double` cannot represent many values like 0.01 *exactly* and so
`(int)(start * 100)` fails edge cases when the minutes * 100 are a fraction just less than a whole number as `(int)` truncates.

Instead break the FP value into whole and fraction parts (`modf()`) to get the hours and minutes and then form a total single unit time  value.  Add.  Then convert the sum back to hours.minutes.

Makes more sense to use `double` than `float` given OP is using `double` test case constants. Also `float` should be reserved for compelling conditions that require/benefit from them instead of the default `double`.

No need to scale to minutes.  Makes for simpler code.  [Easy-peasy](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/easy_peasy).

```
#include <math.h>

double to_hours(double hours_dot_minutes) {
  double h;
  double m = modf(hours_dot_minutes, &h) * 100.0;
  return h + m/60.0;
}

double reduce_to_a_day(double hours) {
  const double hours_per_day = 24.0;
  hours = fmod(hours, hours_per_day);
  if (hours < 0.0) {
    hours += hours_per_day;
  }
  return hours;
}

double to_hours_dot_minutes(double hours) {
  double h;
  double m = modf(hours, &h) * 60.0;
  return h + m/100.0;
}

double walking(double start, double duration) {
  double sum = to_hours(start) + to_hours(duration);
  sum = reduce_to_a_day(sum);
  return to_hours_dot_minutes(sum);
}
```

Notice that `int` math is not used anywhere.  IMO, floating point problems best handled with FP math, integer problems with integer math and text problems with text manipulation.  Mixing approaches often encounters issues in edge cases - as in OP's use of `(int)` for a FP problem.

---

If still wanting to use a cast over a limited range of values,

```
double walking(double start, double duration) {
  int start_h = (int) start;
  int duration_h = (int) duration;
         
  double sum = start_h + duration_h + 
      ((start - start_h) + (duration - duration_h)) * 100.0 / 60.0;
  while  (sum >= 24.0) sum -= 24.0;
  int sum_h = (int) sum;
  return sum_h + (sum - sum_h) * 60.0 / 100.0;
}
```